# Characterization of Noetherian module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, noetherian

I guess this is a simple question but I don't see the answer.

Definition: $M$ is Noetherian if every chain of submodules stabilize.

Theorem: $M$ is Noetherian module iff every nonempty set $S$ of submodules of M contains at least one maximal element.

Should this maximal element be in the set? The book I use says that if $S$ is finite it contains maximum element but I think that two submodules are not necessarily comparable by inclusion. (Take submodules of integers generated by 6 and 9 for example. They have nonempty intersection but non of them is included in the other. In the same time integers is Noetherian module over itself)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Yes, "every nonempty set $S$ of submodules of $M$ **contains**" means $S$ contains such maximal element.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff so what about my example?

Comment: Note that without such condition, $M$ is always a maximal.

Comment: Maximal elements aren't necessarily maximum. Perhaps you should check the definition of maximal element.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Oh.. I see. If we have two elements in the set and they are not comparable then any of them is maximal element.

Comment: Maximal here means ‘not contained in another element of the set’.